# Trouble with ARP Spoofing with a Virtual Machine in my real Network

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to test my Python-based ARP spoofing program in a Kali Linux virtual machine running on VirtualBox on my PC. The VM is connected to my network using a network bridge, allowing me to reach other devices on my network. However, I'm encountering a problem when I attempt to launch the ARP spoofing program and attack my laptop within the network.

The issue I'm experiencing is that once the ARP spoofing starts running, the ARP cache of my laptop gets updated with the MAC address of my PC (where VirtualBox is running), but it does not update with the MAC address of the Kali Linux VM, which can be found using "ifconfig" within the VM. It does update with the MAC address of my PC. As a result, my laptop loses internet connectivity. Whenever I try to access a website in the browser, nothing happens.

Some additional things to consider: I don't have an additional Wi-Fi stick for my Kali Linux VM. IP forwarding was enabled before starting ARP spoofing and remained active throughout the process. The program works fine with all other VMs used as victims in the NAT-network-network. I also disabled my antivirus system on the laptop. It's not just my custom ARP spoofing program that is not working, but also the arpspoof tool from the Kali Linux tools.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Is your PC (the one with the Kali VM on it) connected to the network using Ethernet or Wi-Fi?

Comment: If Wireless, does Kali support the particular WiFi if a separate card?

Comment: @u1686_grawity my pc with the vm on it is connected via wifi to my home router.

Comment: @John how can i check this?

Comment: Look in the Kali  Network settings.  I use a Panda Wireless USB card.

Answer (score 0):

Wi-Fi client devices cannot send frames from more than one MAC address. The MAC of the radio that connected to the AP is implicitly the MAC of the frames that are sent.

To deal with this, VirtualBox "bridge" driver has to perform L2 NAT – it rewrites the frames coming from VMs to have your host system's MAC in the header, *and* it rewrites ARP requests and responses accordingly. Your VM thinks it's bridged but the rest of your LAN only sees a single MAC address.

To use a VM as a gateway you'll need either a dedicated Wi-Fi interface for the VM or a wired Ethernet connection for the VM host.

Comment: So the solution would be a alfa wifi stick for my vm for example?